# Merge-conflict-free way to git stash changes

Tags: git, git-stash

If I `git stash -k` (stash all unstaged changes) and `git pop`, I get merge conflicts if one of the files was modified in the staging area and also had an unstaged change.

I'm writing a script that calls `git stash -k`, lints the files, and commits them if they pass. If not, I'd like to `git stash pop` and return the working tree to precisely its previous state.

Is this possible? Is there a merge-conflict-free way of achieving this?

Thank you!

Comment: You're going to have to solve the merge conflicts anyway. What I would do is create another branch, reset to the commit where you created the files and do a `git stash apply.

Now come back to the original branch and do a `git merge --strategy='Whichever you prefer'`. Maybe you could pass the strategy as a variable..

Answer (score 0):

You can do it another way:

1. Do a commit.
2. `git stash` (or even better, `git stash -u`)
3. Run tests.
4. `git stash pop`
5. If tests failed, undo commit with `git reset --soft HEAD^`